# How can I convert JToken to string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I am trying to read an array from a JObject into a string[] but I cannot figure out how.

The code is very simple as below but does not work. Fails with error cannot convert JToken to string[]

```
JObject Items = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<JObject>(jtr);
string[] brands = null;
brands = (string[])Items.SelectToken("Documents[0].Brands");
```

The following works when I want to read a simple bool so I know I am in the right place.

```
IsAdmin = (bool)Items.SelectToken("Documents[0].IsAdmin");
```

the JObject in Documents[0] looks as follows

```
{
    "id": "961AA6A6-F372-ZZZZ-1270-ZZZZZ",
    "ApiKey": "SDKTest",
    "ConsumerName": "SDKTest",
    "IsAdmin": false,
    "Brands": [
        "ZZZ"
    ],
    "IsSdkUser": true
}
```

How can I read that Brands array into my string[] brands?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) to deserialize a `JToken` to any compatible .Net type, i.e.

```
var brands = Items.SelectToken("Documents[0].Brands")?.ToObject<string []>();
```

Casting operations on `JToken` such as `(bool)Items.SelectToken("Documents[0].IsAdmin")` only work for primitive types for which Newtonsoft has supplied an explicit or implicit conversion operator, all of which are documented in [JToken Type Conversions](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Operators_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm).  Since no such conversion operator was implemented for `string[]`, deserialization is necessary.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7YdBME).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.Values<T>` to retrieve the values of the `JToken` and cast them to the desired type.

```
var brands = Items["Documents"][0]["Brands"].Values<string>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Create C# classes from the below json using [this tool](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp) or in VS `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes`.
2. Install `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget package
3. Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize the json to C# classes.
4. The `root` object now contains everything you've ever wanted!

file.json

```
{
  "Documents": [
    {
      "id": "961AA6A6-F372-ZZZZ-1270-ZZZZZ",
      "ApiKey": "SDKTest",
      "ConsumerName": "SDKTest",
      "IsAdmin": false,
      "Brands": [
        "ZZZ"
      ],
      "IsSdkUser": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"file.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            var brands = root.Documents[0].Brands; // brands = {"ZZZ"}
        }
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Document[] Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public string[] Brands { get; set; }
    public bool IsSdkUser { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static T[] JTokenToArray<T>(JToken jToken)
{
    List<T> ret = new List<T>();
    foreach (JToken jItem in jToken)
        ret.Add(jItem.Value<T>());
    return ret.ToArray();
}
```

Usage:

`string[] brands = JTokenToArray<string>(jObject.Value<JToken>("brands"));`