# jtoken question. Alternatives to selectToken?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a piece of code that works. Looks like this (simplified)

```
myObj.data1 = (string)executive.SelectToken("$.value.name1");
myObj.data2 = (string)executive.SelectToken("$.value.name2");
```

executive is a JToken.

I want to see what the whole "executive" looks like (the whole thing). Unfortunately I cannot debug in this project. However I can debug in another project where I can see "myObj". I am adding a new field to myObj called "executiveRaw" where I want to see how "executive" looks like. How can I achieve this? something like this:

```
myObj.executiveRaw = (string)executive.somethingSomething("$.value");
```

I found this stackoverflow post [How can I convert JToken to string[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729632/how-can-i-convert-jtoken-to-string) but this is to convert to an array of strings, not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just `executive.ToString()`

Comment: didn't work.....

Comment: Can you provide some example to clarify your expectations? How do you get `executive` and what's your expectation from `executiveRaw`? Explain it with some json body for the best understanding